# Java Complex Path Collision

Tags: java, random, collision-detection

I've been having trouble with collision in my randomly generated dungeon maze game. So basically, my game randomly generates rooms and pathways between them. However, the way I detect collision is by Rectangles:

```
public Rectangle getBounds(){
    return new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
}
```

Since I use Rectangles to detect the collision, whenever I try to leave a room and go into a pathway, the room's collision rectangle prevents me from doing so. 
[image: Dungeon Generation]

Me Me(blue box) attempting to going into a green pathway(but I can't because of the room's collision rectangle), red boxes are the rooms, blue outlines are the collision boxes.

Is there a way for me to fix this, or a better way to detect collision?

Comment: You can always amend your collision code to ignore collisions when you are on the boundary of, or are directly on a green pathway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your collision code to not use `Rectangle`s for the rooms but instead use `Line`s. `Rectangle`s in java conveniently have a collision detection method for `Line`s with `Rectangle`s.

```
Line2D.interects(Rectangle r)
```

With your player having a rectangular collision mask this is kind of how it would look in the player `class`. **Note:** code is missing in example like updating player mask and declaration of `List<Line2D.Float> walls` in level class.(or wherever you have it)

```
Rectangle mask = new Rectangle.Float(x, y, width, height);

protected boolean wallCollision() {
     for (Line2D.Float l : level.walls) {
          if (l.intersects(this.mask)
               return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: As for your level generator, I suggest looking up some maze generator algorithms for java, it shouldn't be too hard to find.